# Could not load file or assembly ServiceStack.Text The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I'm trying to use the json deserializer in my VS2008 C# Windows service program and am getting the above error as soon as a client sends data to the service via TCP.  The error always occurs on:

```
protected virtual void OnDataReceived(DataEventArgs e)
{
EventHandler<DataEventArgs> handler = DataReceived;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, e);   <-- error happens here
  }
}
```

I've include `ServiceStack.Text` as a reference in my solution and used the statement `using ServiceStack.Text;`  The only code I'm using is:

```
o = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString <Dictionary<string, string>>(sAry[2]);
```

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more info... The subscriber of the OnDataReceived event is where the serialization takes place. Something happened above to the format of the line in question. It should be: o = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString <Dictionary<string, string>>(sAry[2]); which I copied from the web somewhere.

Comment: See my attempted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23716548/430885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please search for "fusion log viewer" and use it to investigate assembly loading failures.

Most likely you are not copying DLL to bin folder during build (Should be "Copy local=true" in properties) OR that assembly have dependencies on other files that you are not copying/installing correctly.

Comment: I got nothing in the log viewer running it from the VS command prompt as admin. I even changed each of the options and got the error, but nothing in the log.  I did verify that the .dll is in the bin/debug directory with service.  I copied all ServiceStack .dll's there too just to make sure I had everything of theirs.

Comment: Ok, you had the basic problem.  This is a Windows Service and to debug it you have to install it.  So, I installed it in another directory (production), not bin/debug.  So I copied the ServiceStack.Text.dll to the production directory and it worked.

Comment: To find the fusion log viewer check out this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx as it's location and name are not obvious (Fuslogvw.exe)